# Are parquet files written incrementally via pyarrow's ParquetWriter visible to others before the writer has been closed?

Tags: parquet, pyarrow

I am trying to figure out whether a parquet file being written to incrementally by pyarrow's `ParquetWriter` would be visible to others before the `close()` method is called.

I've tried running some experiments and so far it seems that the file is *not* visible, but my observations could be due to some internal memory caching of the writer. I'd appreciate the opinion of an expert here :-)

EDIT: just to clarify, I'm not trying to load the file *before* the batch write is complete, but quite the opposite: I'd like to prevent other clients from seeing the file as it is being written and not yet "completed".

Answer (score 1):

In a parquet file, the meta data is put at the end of the file, in a footer (instead of a header). It means you can't open the file until the ParquetWriter is done (and has written the footer).

If you want to be able to read data while it is being written, either write data in smaller batch, each batch in a different file.

Or you could also use the [arrow IPC format](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/ipc.html) which writes the meta data in the header (but unlike parquet doesn't do any compression).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I realize my question was not clear - I'm not looking for ways to make the data visible, but the other way around: I want to ensure that no other clients can see the file as it's being incrementally written.

Comment: I guess you could write the file somewhere else and move it once complete. Or you could have the code that read the data try to create `pyarrow.parquet.ParquetFile` which should fail very quickly if the file hasn't been written completely

Comment: Indeed, writing to a temp file first would be my plan B, in case it is confirmed that clients _might_ end up seeing the parquet file while it's being written to incrementally.

Comment: @GabrieleGiuseppini I'm not sure what you think happens in a ”non incrementally” case.  Writing a file is *always* incremental as it is not an atomic operation on most file systems.  The usual solution is to write the file under a temporary name and then rename it to the final name, as renaming *is* atomic on most file systems.

Comment: @BlackJack, indeed - I was hoping that the implementation of `ParquetWriter` would offer such atomicity.